# Vue how to traverse the list correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I just writed the vue simple code, But unable to follow the HTML effect. After traversal rendering a bit wrong. If gift object is no, for example the goods object has two data, `goods_b1` + `goods_b2`. But i want to follow the HTML effect. Go to the [HTML still](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/4b5Lf1ab/). And go to the [vue loops](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/wLtopdv3/).

#### I want to the this effect:

[image]

#### Look at the javascript:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'A',
      goods: [{
        name: "goods_a1"
      }],
      gift: [{
        name: "gift_a1",
      }]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'B',
      gift: [],
      goods: [{
        name: "goods_b1"
      }, {
        name: "goods_b2"
      }],
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'C',
      goods: [{
        name: "goods_c1"
      }, {
        name: "goods_c2"
      }, {
        name: "goods_c3"
      }],
      gift: [{
        name: "gift_c1",
      }]
    }]
  }
})
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="mui-row" v-for="item in list">
    <div class="span-title-main">
      <span class="span-title">{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <div class="mui-col" v-for="items in item.goods">
          <span class="span-name">{{items.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="addspan">+</div>
        <div class="mui-col" v-for="itemss in item.gift">
          <span class="span-name">{{itemss.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="addspan">+</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking that the (+) being inside the loop of your goods and gift ?

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="mui-row" v-for="item in list">
    <div class="span-title-main">
      <span class="span-title">{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <div class="mui-col" v-for="items in item.goods">
          <span class="span-name">{{items.name}}</span>
          <div class="addspan">+</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mui-col" v-for="itemss in item.gift">
          <span class="span-name">{{itemss.name}}</span>

        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Remove the (+) for gifts loop as requested by OP.

Note: if the OP is asking to have a style for element in between goods and gift. I would suggest to use the css `:last` selector with a `display:none` to have this kind of effect.

Comment: Just follow the effect on it, but behind can not have that the (+).

Comment: So not having the + on the gift ? Just remove the span on the gift loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only difference is that you want a `+` button to appear after each `item.goods` instead of just one after the loop.

So put it inside the loop:

```
    <template v-for="items in item.goods"><!-- using "template" to avoid modifying your html structure; you could of course use any tag -->
      <div class="mui-col">
        <span class="span-name">{{items.name}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="addspan">+</div>
    </template>
    <div class="mui-col" v-for="items in item.gift">
      <span class="span-name">{{items.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <!-- your image doesn't show a + button after gifts, so I've omitted it here -->
```